# Como hacer una ruta get con parámetro que use un controlador?

Tags: php

¿Cual es el sintaxis correcto para que una ruta get que tiene un parámetro dinámico (Ejemplo: "compras/{id}") trabaje con un controlador y su metodo?

Es decir, algo así pero con un parámetro dinámico:

```
Route::get('registry/people', 'PersonController@index');
```

Comment: que operación es la que deseas llevar a cabo al pasar `people` como parámetro?

Comment: es decir solo tratas de mostrar la información asociada a ese valor dinámico que pases? por ejemplo el id?

Comment: Necesito hacer algo como 'registry/people/{id}', 'PersonController@edit', pero no se como pasar el parametro correctamente

Comment: Así está bien...

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la pregunta está mas orientada a como hacer uso de este parámetro, mas que incorporarlo en la url, que por lo visto en el ejemplo tienes idea de como hacerlo. Entonces vamos con los ejemplos.

Para añadirlo a tu ruta basta con hacerlo del siguiente modo:

```
Route::get('registry/people/{id}', 'PersonController@index');
```

Para usar este parametro en tu controlador, lo debes hacer del siguiente modo:

```
Public function index($id)
{
    //código en donde lo vas a usar...
}
```

Si lo requiere puede pasarle multiples parametros. Por ejemplo:

Ruta:

```
Route::get('users/{id}/posts/{idPost}', 'PostController@show');
```

Acción show:

```
Public function show($id, $idPost)
{
    //código en donde lo vas a usar...
}
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera

`Route::get('registry/people/{id}', 'PersonController@index');`

y si quieres ponerle nombre a la ruta lo haces asi

`Route::get('registry/people/{id}', 'PersonController@index')->name('nombre-que-quieras');`